# How to add Min/Max input restriction for user input?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular application, I have an input field where I want the user to enter an input value between 0-100. I used min/max attribute, but it's not working. How can I restrict users from entering input value less than 0 and more than 100?

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
   <input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="row.id" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" id="id" name="Id">
    <input  type="number"[(ngModel)]="row.percent_complete" min="0" max= "100"> 
</mat-form-field>



 <div class="submit-button">
    <ion-button color="primary" expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit Changes</ion-button>
  </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
 onSubmit() {

      let postData = [];

      this.deltasByGroupId[this.selectedGroupId] = this.measures;

      for (var groupId in this.deltasByGroupId) {
        if (!this.deltasByGroupId.hasOwnProperty(groupId)) { continue }

        for (var k in this.deltasByGroupId[groupId]) {
          if (!this.deltasByGroupId[groupId].hasOwnProperty(k)) { continue }

          let secs = this.deltasByGroupId[groupId][k];

          var item1 = secs["items"]
          for (var j in item1) {

            var item2 = item1[j]
            for (var l in item2) {

              var listItem = item2["items"]
              for (var li in listItem) {
                this.model = new MeasurementChange(listItem[li].id, listItem[li].percent_complete);
                postData.push(this.model);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      this.pEntryService.postEntries(postData).subscribe(res => {
        this.localDialogRef.close();

        Swal(
          'Success!',
          'Form Submitted Sucessfully!',
          'success',
        )
      })

    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Will you consider using reactive forms? It is a natively available in Angular (doesnt require additional libraries)

Answer (score 2):

```
<input  type=number[(ngModel)]="row.percent_complete" min="0" max= "100">
```

there are couple of mistake here.

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="row.percent_complete" min="0" max= "100">
```

number should come between double quotes and there must be space between ngModel and number

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100">
```

Comment: make sure your your define number with quotes `type="number"`

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing the min and max attributes too but it was not working so I used the reactive form method validation but even with that users input was not restricted above the maximum set while typing but it works while using the number cursor.

I suggest disabling and enabling the button based on the form being valid. This was what I did eventually and it worked but I will not mind if anyone has a better solution that worked.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem! Min/Max works with works while using the number cursor, but doesn't work while typing.

Answer (score 1):

Using HTML `min` and `max` attributes only limit how high and low number cursors will allow. It won't prevent user from inputting his own numbers. A bit different situation is with reactive forms, adding `Validators.min()` and `Validators.max()` will make limit form validity. That means, user can still input bigger values, but form will become invalid. Disabling button with `[disabled]="form.invalid"` will prevent user from clicking on it.
If this is not good enoug for you, you can always split `[(ngModel)]` into seperate `[ngModel]="row.percent_complete"` and `(ngModelChange)="myCheck($event)"`. And inside your `myCheck` function you can manually check new value, and if you don't like it, ignore it.

```
myCheck(event: number) {
  // only assign if value is valid
  if (event <= max && event >= min){
    this.row.percent_complete = event;
  }
}
```

Same can be achieved with reactive forms, using `.valueChanges` method.

Comment: @BernoulliIT sorry about that. The actual value does not get updated above/below min/max and remains unchanged, but the input will show invalid value. If you want actual validation you need to create additional elements in HTML. Below input you should create an span that will show errors. This will NOT prevent user from inputting higher numbers, but will show errors when he does. More info on this can be found here https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: clear explanation and also what was experienced during testing :/ What should be the reason to NOT correct a value outside of min/max inherently in the HTML input itself?

Comment: I guess, in this case the reason to keep user input value as it is would be clarity. With normal validation user will see what did he input, even if it's wrong, and he will also see error saying what values are valid. For ex. You don't replace user input age from 200 to 20 when he makes an error, you highlight his value in (usually) red color and write an error message saying what valid value range is